# How to let SQL Server know not to use Cache in Queries?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-execution-plan

Just a general question:

Is there a query/command I can pass to SQL Server not to use cache when executing a particularly query?

I am looking for a query/command that I can set rather than a configuration setting. Is there no need to do this?

Comment: I can't think of a reason you would want to do this and I've never seen it done either. What are you trying to fix?

Comment: It could be useful for measuring the average time taken to execute a query when the cache cannot be used.

Comment: @Jvilata -> you would do this when u wish to fix up the raw performance for a stored procedure or query. The slowest time a query/sp is ran, is when it's first compiled because it's not cached ... and that's excluding whatever the query is suppose to do/return back. So if u can fix the performance of a query/sp when it hasn't been cached, then you know the worst case scenario for that query (more or less).

Comment: Reading below, seems like the answer is "no, there is not a way to pass a query to SQL Server and tell it not to use the cache when executing that query."  Is that right?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
```

Will remove all cached procedures execution plans. This would cause all subsequent procedure calls to be recompiled.

Adding `WITH RECOMPILE` to a procedure definition would cause the procedure to be recompiled every time it was called.

I do not believe that (in SQL 2005 or earlier) there is any way to clear the procedrue cache of a single procedures execution plan, and I'd doubt you could do it in 2008 either.

Comment: You can remove an individual plan by using the following SQL.

    DBCC FREEPROCCACHE [ ( { plan_handle | sql_handle | pool_name } ) ] [ WITH NO_INFOMSGS ]

Answer (score 29):

If you want to force a query to not use the data cache, the best approach is to clear the cache before you run the query:

```
CHECKPOINT
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
```

Note that forcing a recompile will have no effect on the query's use of the data cache.

One reason you can't just mark an individual query to avoid the cache is the cache use is an integral part of executing the query.  If the data is already in cache, then what would SQL Server do with the data if it was read a second time?  Not to mention sync issues, etc.

Answer (score 12):

Another more localized way to not use the MS-SQL Server Cache is to use the `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` keyword at the *end* of your statement.

E.g.

```
SELECT Columnname
FROM TableName
OPTION(RECOMPILE)
```

For more information about this and other similar query-cache clues to help identify problems with a query, Pinal Dave (no affiliation) [has some helpful info about this.](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2020/04/06/sql-server-sql_no_cache-and-option-recompile/)

Answer (score 3):

use

```
WITH RECOMPILE
```