# linq to entity speed is too slower than direct SQL statement with like expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql

I have one very simple LINQ to Entity Code to query the data from SQL Server Database. And I have two tables "MES_WO_Master" "MES_WO_Tracking", table "MES_WO_Master" has index on columns "WoNo" & "MaterialNo", table "MES_WO_Tracking" has index on column "EndDate". 
LINQ to Entity is as below:

```
from w in MES_WO_Master
                        join r in MES_WO_Tracking
                        on w.WoNo equals r.WoNo
                        where r.EndDate >= DateTime.Parse("2013-01-02") && r.EndDate <= DateTime.Parse("2013-01-03") && r.QtyScrap > 0 && w.MaterialNo.EndsWith("-W")
                        select new
                        {
                            WoNo = w.WoNo,
                            MaterialNo = w.MaterialNo,
                            QtyComplete = r.QtyComplete.Value,
                            QtyScrap = r.QtyScrap.Value,
                            ScrapCode = r.ScrapCode,
                            EndDate = r.EndDate.Value
                        }
```

And this LINQ To Entity need to excute over 30 secs to get the data. I used the LINQPad to get the actual SQL statement of this LINQ. The Statement as below:

```
    -- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 VARCHAR(20)
SET @p0 = '2013-01-02'
DECLARE @p1 VARCHAR(20)
SET @p1 = '2013-01-03'
DECLARE @p2 BIGINT
SET @p2 = 0
DECLARE @p3 VARCHAR(3)
SET @p3 = '%-W'
-- EndRegion
SELECT  [t0].[WoNo] ,
        [t0].[MaterialNo] ,
        [t1].[QtyComplete] AS [QtyComplete] ,
        [t1].[QtyScrap] AS [QtyScrap] ,
        [t1].[ScrapCode] ,
        [t1].[EndDate] AS [EndDate]
FROM    [MES_WO_Master] AS [t0]
        INNER JOIN [MES_WO_Tracking] AS [t1] ON [t0].[WoNo] = [t1].[WoNo]
WHERE   ( [t1].[EndDate] >= @p0 )
        AND ( [t1].[EndDate] <= @p1 )
        AND ( [t1].[QtyScrap] > @p2 )
        AND ( [t0].[MaterialNo] LIKE @p3 )
```

But if I replace @p3 with "%-W" and execute the statement in SQL Server analysis window as below, it only take no more than 1 Sec.

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 VARCHAR(20)
SET @p0 = '2013-01-02'
DECLARE @p1 VARCHAR(20)
SET @p1 = '2013-01-03'
DECLARE @p2 BIGINT
SET @p2 = 0
DECLARE @p3 VARCHAR(3)
SET @p3 = '%-W'
-- EndRegion
SELECT  [t0].[WoNo] ,
        [t0].[MaterialNo] ,
        [t1].[QtyComplete] AS [QtyComplete] ,
        [t1].[QtyScrap] AS [QtyScrap] ,
        [t1].[ScrapCode] ,
        [t1].[EndDate] AS [EndDate]
FROM    [MES_WO_Master] AS [t0]
        INNER JOIN [MES_WO_Tracking] AS [t1] ON [t0].[WoNo] = [t1].[WoNo]
WHERE   ( [t1].[EndDate] >= @p0 )
        AND ( [t1].[EndDate] <= @p1 )
        AND ( [t1].[QtyScrap] > @p2 )
        AND ( [t0].[MaterialNo] LIKE ***'%-W'***)
```

I know '%-W' will not use index, but why these two statements will have such big gap? Could someone give me some tips? Thanks a lot.

Jake

Comment: One second is still too slow, unless you have enormous amounts of data.  There might be a problem with one of your indexes, or something.  What does your execution plan say?

Comment: Are you saying that if you run the first query in SSMS and then run the second query in SSMS, that the performance is 30:1 different?  If so, I would try to paste both queries in a window (you can do the variable declaration stuff only once) and then running the whole batch with the "include actual execution plan" turned on and see if you can see what the difference is.  SQL Server will tell you how it's returning the data.  Please note what is different.

Comment: Are you on .NET Framework 4? if so this looks like this: (http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/709906/entity-framework-linq-provider-defaulting-to-unicode-when-translating-string-contains-to-like-clause). It was fixed in .NET Framework 4.5

Answer (score 0):

The reason the second query takes only 1 second is because it's cached after it gets run the first time. If you run the same query immediately after it will take less time. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873025/how-can-i-clear-the-sql-server-query-cache)

If you follow the instructions there you will be able to see if the difference in execution times is entity being slow vs if it's with the caching.

You could also look at the query plan the SQL is generating to see why it's taking so long, [Here's another SO question telling you how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359702/how-do-i-obtain-a-query-execution-plan).