# run script in multiple Dbs query return error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am running a query with the `sp_MSforeachdb` stored procedure.  I used three databases which exist in my server instance: ExcelineDev, EXCE_NR1, and EXCE_AKI.

```
declare @t table (dbname varchar(50),ss varchar(max),sss varchar(max))
DECLARE @command varchar(max)

SELECT @command = 'IF ''?'' IN (''ExcelineDev'',''EXCE_NR1'',''EXCE_AKI'') 
BEGIN USE ? 
EXEC
(''
select DB_NAME(DB_ID()), category,name from usrpt.report
where name like ''''%leders%''''
'')
END'

print @command
insert into @t
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command
select * from @t
```

I'm getting the following error:

> 'Msg 911, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Database 'Migration_Release_1'
>   does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.'

I'm confused, because there is no DB called 'Migration_Release_1' in my server instance. Why is SQL searching for this database?

Comment: we are not passing a variable there..it acts like the DB variable

Comment: run this: `Select name from master.dbo.sysdatabases`.  Is there any entry for Migration_Release_1 in that result set?

Comment: no..i run that and checked...i think it's due to deleting  Migration_Release_1 DB without closing all the connections...

Comment: My suggestion would be to pull up the text of the sp_MSForEachDB procedure and manually walk through it until you figure out which query is picking up that database value.  Perhaps the query results are cached and [clearing the server's buffers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873025/how-can-i-clear-the-sql-server-query-cache) might eliminate the problem.