# Improving First-Time Query Performance in SQL Server for Data Migration Scenarios

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization, sqlperformance

How can I improve the performance of my initial query execution in SQL Server, given that I do not want to rely on caching because I will not be running the same query again due to data migration between tables?

I have noticed that the first query takes significantly longer compared to subsequent executions which return results much faster.

Is there any way to stop SQL Server from caching for a few executions?

Answer (score 0):

So you are saying that you don't want to use caching, Did you search about disabling the cache on the queries?

Duplicate?: [How to let SQL Server know not to use Cache in Queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856966/how-to-let-sql-server-know-not-to-use-cache-in-queries)

Duplicate?: [How can I clear the SQL Server query cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873025/how-can-i-clear-the-sql-server-query-cache)

Duplicate?: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1360/clearing-cache-for-sql-server-performance-testing/

Comment: Hi , I my question is not about the usuage of the cache. I donot want my results to be cached but I am ok to get the results from cache if any !